# Wait for a process (identified by name) to terminate un wix uninstall

Tags: windows, wix

I need to wait for a process to terminate (takes about 30 sec) during wix uninstall before deleting files it has open. I know the name ("Image Name" in task manager) of the target process. This process is not a child process of an application or service so those normal mechanisms are not working.

If not that, can I just pause for 30 sec before the file delete happens in the uninstall process?

Comment: Does your comment about "not a child process" mean that you've tried WiX util CloseApplication (with a TimeOut?) and it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't have a Windows application at all. I just looked at docs for CloseApplication and noticed Target & TerminateProcess, can that be used to terminate a exe/process that is not a Windows application?

Comment: The preferred method is to send a close message to the app (which is what CloseApplication can do) so that the process closes down normally. If the process has no message loop (COM STA or Windows) then you could use the 30sec timeout followed by the terminate as the docs say. Should be easy to test?